# Android app payments now charged after 10 hours instead of 24 hours?

Tags: android, google-checkout

Anyone else notice Google Checkout now initiates charges for Android apps after 10 hours instead of 24?

Comment: what charges dude ? do you pay money for apps you put on sale ?

Comment: @Miloud B, he is telling about charges from users, who have bought an app. The charges seems to appear faster in checkout.

Comment: Yes, Vladimir is right. Usually Google Checkout authorizes payment when the user purchases the app but only actually charges the credit card (or whatever) 24 hours later. Now the timeframe appears to have been reduced to 10 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is because the refund period was reduced from 24h to 15min with the new Android Market. See [here](http://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=134336&hl=en)

Therefore they consider, that you like the app after 10h and charge you.

Comment: This change only happened in the last couple of days, whereas the 15min refund window changed a few weeks ago. They are probably related, however.